# How do I events to detect custom key presses in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to create an event that if used with `.on()`, will detect if I press two custom keys, let's say X and Z.

This is what I expected to happen with my code. I would create two custom events like this:

```
xDown = $.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 88});
zDDown = $.Event( "keydown", { keycode: 89}); // 88 and 89 are the keycodes for x and z.
```

And then those events would be triggered by:

```
$(document).on("xDown",function() {
    // do stuff
});
$(document).on("zDown",function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

But I think events don't work that way. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 88) {
        doAction88();
    } else if (e.which == 89) {
        doAction88();
    }
});
```